# How to initialize the data for each invocation in JMH?

Tags: java, jmh

I'm trying to create the benchmark that modifies the collection.
The problem is that I don't know how to initialize data for each invocation.

Assume that Test.DATA is a collection that contains 200 elements.
The `test` method removes data based on `a.isTrue()`'s value.
I know that `@Setup` is similar to JUnit's `@Setup`. I want to use `@Before`
but I couldn't find one in JMH. 
How can I initialize the data each time before the `test` method is invoked?
Thank you very much in advance.

```
@State(Scope.Thread)
public class JavaCollectionBenchmark {

    List<Foo> cols;

    @Setup
    public void prepare(){
        cols= new ArrayList<>(Test.DATA);
    }

    @Benchmark
    public long test(){
        if(cols.size() != 200) {
            System.out.println("SECOND TIME DOESN'T WORK!");
            System.exit(0);
        }else{
            System.out.println("FIRST TIME");
        }
        cols.removeIf(a-> a.isTrue());
        return cols.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you read JMH Samples, as suggested in docs? Notably, this example answers your question directly: http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/bcec9a03787f/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_38_PerInvokeSetup.java

Comment: Oh sorry I shouldn't have asked this question when the answer is already in the samples. I admit that I didn't read every code examples. For some reasons, my eyes kept looking at states and fixtures.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check `Level` parameter on `@Setup` annotation. The equivalent of `@Before` is

```
@Setup(Level.Invocation)
```

which is explained, together with many warnings (`WARNING: HERE BE DRAGONS! THIS IS A SHARP TOOL.`, etc.) [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/bcec9a03787f/jmh-core/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/annotations/Level.java)

Comment: Thank you. I already got the answer from the JMH's author in the comment section. I will mark this as an answer for your effort. 
I wrote the article about using JMH: https://medium.com/zappos-engineering/java-8-vs-scala-part-iii-trust-no-one-bench-everything-ef0bbd6e9cdb#.fypijj48e
If you have sometime to review and give me a feedback, I'd appreciate it.